# If a monk sees a pin in his path, will he step on it and accept pain?

Tags: monk

I read about Buddhism where I came to know, we learn to see everything from bare prospect and don't judge anything. And a random thing came to my mind: I even read that pain is seen as pain and nothing more, no bad or good feeling towards pain.

So suppose a Monk happens to see a pin in his path:

- Will he step on it and accept pain, and think of pain as pain and detach from its feeling?
- Or, would he judge the pin which will cause pain and move away?

Moving away shows that he knows its bad to step on the pin.

This was just a question which came to my mind. I don't mean any offence, literally I have no idea of it.

Comment: Hello Mukil and welcome to Buddhism SE. We have also a [*Help Center*](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) with resources for new comers that you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have not read in original Buddhism we learn to see everything from bare prospect and don't judge anything (apart from possibly one popular yet questionable teaching, at this [link](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.1.10.than.html)).

Buddhism teaches, about all things experienced by the senses, their origination, passing away, attraction, danger & escape from their danger should be comprehended (at this [link](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.088.than.html)).

> *...discern, as they actually are present, the origination, the passing away, the allure, the drawback and the escape from the six
> spheres of contact.*
>
> *Punna Sutta*

Answer (score 1):

What would the monk be accepting? The monk would likely accept walking around the pin. A well practiced monk knows the appropriate path isn't always the intended path. The path a well practiced monk trys to make is the most appropriate path and not necessarily someone else's idea of an  appropriate  path.

Answer (score 0):

When *Wisdom* is gained through the practice of insight meditation one learns to navigate more skillfully in Samsara, i.e. to reduce the amount of suffering for oneself and others, through wholesome/skillful deeds, motivated by wholesome intentions.

Skillful action would not be to purposely inflict suffering onto oneself.

Answer (score 0):

If that Monk have common sense he will avoid the pin. no one will accept intentional self pain.  if he cannot avoid the pain he will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

A Monk trains himself in *sila (moral discipline)*, which includes not intentionally hurting living beings. Since he himself is a living being, he should respect and protect his life as he would others.